# Variable will not work in switch case

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean

When I try to compile the following:

`bool matrix[h][w];`

```
bool c = 0;
switch(1) // was close?
{
  case matrix[y][x-1]: // up 1
  case matrix[y-2][x-1]: // down 1
  case matrix[y-1][x]: // right 1
  case matrix[y][x-2]: // left 1
    c = 1;
    break;
}
```

It returns `the value of 'matrix' is not usable in a constant expression`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably misunderstood what `switch` statement does.

Comment: @Krii what you want to do ?

Comment: @Zereges Then what *does* a switch statement do?

Comment: Cases must be constant, unfortunately.

Comment: It looks like you might want an if statement, not a switch statement.

Comment: @Ajay `matrix` is a 10x10 grid of bools, I want to see if there are any `true` values "close" to the value entered by the user if the value is `false`.

Comment: Yeah, then you definitely want something like if (matrix[x-1]....)

Comment: You may want to use the `break` statement to prevent one `case` from flowing into the following `case`.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is downvoted so heavily. The user provided a minimally reproducible example, and the question was clear and valid; just the result of misunderstanding the correct usage of a feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expressions used in the `case` statements need to be compile time constants. You can use:

```
case 1:

case 2:
```

etc, not

```
case matrix[y][x-1]: // up 1

case matrix[y-2][x-1]: // down 1
```

Also, the operand of switch() should be a runtime variable, not a compile-time constant. For example, `switch(matrix[y][x-1])` would be fine.

Comment: Also, the operand of `switch()` should be a runtime variable, not a compile-time constant. For example, `switch(matrix[y][x-1])` would be fine.